# How to get recent Kernel on ubuntu 18.04 including linux-tools

Tags: 18.04, kernel

The "mainline" tools, using packages from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) allows to upgrade Ubuntu's kernel to a recent one. But unfortunately this repository does not include the linux-tools package that I need for "cpupower" of "perf".

What would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Kernel PPA doesn't seem to have binary `linux-tools` packages.

Other alternatives could be:

1. Install a new Ubuntu release that has a newer kernel.
2. Install an Ubuntu kernel (HWE).
3. Build `linux-tools` from source.
4. Install an Ubuntu kernel from a newer release (not recommended).